# Spanning content within a tabbing environment across multiple pages

Tags: minipage, cv, tabbing

I'm trying to update a CV I wrote a long time ago based on the [Wilson Resume](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/wilson-resume-cv) template.

However, I've run into an issue in which the content I've added for a job listed in my career history is too long, and since it can't break across pages the typesetter has put it all on a separate page:

[image]

What I'd like is it to just run the job details onto a new page if it gets too long without shifting the entire thing onto the new page. I haven't worked with LaTeX in a while so I'm pretty rusty with it. The template I use defines the following command that I use to list each job:

```
\newcommand{\job}[6]{
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{2cm} \= \kill
\textbf{#1} \> \href{#4}{#3} \\
\textbf{#2} \>\+ \textit{#5} \\
\begin{minipage}{\smallertextwidth}
\vspace{2mm}
#6
\end{minipage}
\end{tabbing}
\vspace{2mm}
}
```

In this command, `#6` is replaced by the long job description.

I've tried playing around with this command by e.g. trying to remove the minipage environment. However, almost anything I do to modify this command results in dozens of errors that I don't understand. For example, I would expect the following to compile:

```
\newcommand{\job}[6]{
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{2cm} \= \kill
\textbf{#1} \> \href{#4}{#3} \\
\textbf{#2} \>\+ \textit{#5} \\
\vspace{2mm}
#6
\end{tabbing}
\vspace{2mm}
}
```

When I run this through XeLaTeX, it produces the following errors:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with a solution that feels a little bit like a hack, but it works exactly as I intend. I reference the `changepage` package and redefine the `job` command as:

```
\newcommand{\job}[6]{
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{2cm} \= \kill
\textbf{#1} \> \href{#4}{#3} \\
\textbf{#2} \>\+ \textit{#5} \\
\end{tabbing}
\begin{adjustwidth}{2cm}{0pt}
\vspace{2mm}
#6
\vspace{2mm}
\end{adjustwidth}
}
```

I get this output:

[image]